# How to blur background of SliverAppBar on scaled up?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make background of expandable appbar blur when it shrunk.
Where i must write this?
    BackdropFilter(
                  filter: new ImageFilter.blur ...)

This is what i have now:
[image]

It realized like below:

```
NestedScrollView(
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
                  return [
                    SliverAppBar(
                      expandedHeight: 160,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      floating: true,
                      pinned: true,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(...),
                      bottom: TabBar(
                        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        indicatorColor: AppColors.appWhite,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                        isScrollable: true,
                        unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.appWhiteDarker,
                        tabs: buildTypesTabs(types),
                      ),
                    )
                  ];
                },
                body: TabBarView(...),
              )
```

But i need blur effect like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired effect with ImageFilter.blur()

For example, when I want to "blur" all background I put this at the top of a Stack on Scaffold's body:

```
new ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: new BackdropFilter(
              filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0,sigmaY: 5.0),
              child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
              ),
            )
        )
```

I hope it help you ;)

Comment: How do we adapt this to SliverAppBar?